# how to append react component with appendChild method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-component

I have to use the following component more than 1 time.

```
  const OnePen = (props) => {
 return (
   <div className="cerd" key={props.ID}>
     <div className=" card-body">
       <h2 className="card-title">{props.title}</h2>
       <p className="card-text">{props.desc}</p>
     </div>
   </div>
 );
};
export default OnePen;
```

Using the above component, the following code is working fine and doing the perfect job.

```
import OnePen from "./OnePen";
const PensList = ({ pens }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <div id="mainPen" className=" wrapper">
        {pens.map((pen) => (
          **<OnePen ID={pen.id} title={pen.title} desc={pen.description}></OnePen>**
        ))}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default PensList;
```

However, the following code does not work as it says the type of element appending with appendChild should be Node. when I create the same component with react-create-element it works fine but I don't have to do it again and again and I want to reuse the same component.

Here is the code with the problem...
commented code does the job but I don't have to create it like that.. I have to append

```
    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const pen = { title, description };

    axios.post("http://localhost:5000/addPen", pen).then((res) => {
      if (res.status === 200) {
        // const div1 = document.createElement("div");
        // div1.className = "cerd";
        // const key = document.createAttribute("key");
        // key.value = res.data._id;

        // const div2 = document.createElement("div");
        // div2.className = "card-body";

        // const h2 = document.createElement("h2");
        // h2.className = "card-title";
        // h2.innerHTML = res.data.title;

        // const p = document.createElement("p");
        // p.className = "card-text";
        // p.innerHTML = res.data.description;

        // div2.appendChild(h2);
        // div2.appendChild(p);
        // div1.appendChild(div2);

        **document
          .getElementById("mainPen")
          .appendChild(
            <OnePen ID={res.data._id} title={res.data.title} desc={res.data.description}></OnePen>
          );**
      }
    });
  };

  return (
    //some code
  );
};

export default CreatePen;
```

Thanks for considrations

Comment: You should use state for your data. And so react knows when there are new updates, it will re-render the component again. You don't have to control that by yourself

Comment: See the official docs here on how to fetch data and re-render it with setState (or state hook) https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html

Comment: I don't want to rerender the whole component, I just want to append a child component to it.... it there any approach other then appendChild method in DOM....

Comment: Did you check out / try out the answer I provided?

Answer (score 1):

This is how you could approach this.

If you have an API, create an endpoint to fetch data from (all pens or a specific pen). Then, you could make a component where you fetch the data with `axios.get()` and put it in a state variable. If you put this code inside the `useEffect()` hook, the data will be fetched on load of the component.

```js
// state for your pens
const [pens, setPens] = useState([]);

// fetch on load
useEffect(() => {
  axios
    .get("http://localhost:5000/getPens") // set to your endpoint
    .then((response) => {
      setPens(response.data);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
}, []);
```

Then, you could render the pens by mapping through them like you did before to display all of them, or you could display a single pen.

```js
/***********
* Render
***********/
const pensDisplay = pens.map((p, i) => {
  return (
    <div key={i}>
      {/* for example */}
      <p>{p.size}</p>
    </div>
  );
});

return (
  <div>
    <h3>Pens</h3>
    {pensDisplay}
  </div>
);
```

In React, you should avoid using `appendChild()` and such and try doing as much as possible in the "React" way.